# How to avoid remap in vim

Tags: vim

I have the following on my `.vimrc`

```
au FileType ruby nnoremap <expr> <leader>t ':!rspec ' . expand('%') . ':' . line('.')
```

This executes `rspec` on the line specified, and gives me option to edit the line before pressing enter. But I have to be on the test file so it get the file name and line number correctly.

While developing I run `nnoremap <leader>t :!rspec some/spec/file.rb:123` manually to run the test I want from anywhere in the code. So I can code and fire the test without need to visit the test file.

The problem is that if I visit another ruby file the mapping in `.vimrc` runs again and I loose the `nnoremap` command I used before. Is there a command to only map (in normal mode) if there isn't already a map for that sequence?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a buffer-local mapping. Use `<buffer>`:

```
au FileType ruby nnoremap <buffer> <expr> <leader>t ':!rspec ' . expand('%') . ':' . line('.')
```

We can do better!

Use an `augroup` and make is self clearing to make it safe to re-`:source`.

```
augroup ruby_testing
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType ruby nnoremap <buffer> <expr> <leader>t ':!rspec ' . expand('%') . ':' . line('.')
augroup END
```

Even better forgo the `autocmd` and put this mapping in the after directory. Add the following line to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <expr> <leader>t ':!rspec ' . expand('%') . ':' . line('.')
```

For more help see:

```
:h :map-local
:h :augroup
:h after-directory
```

Comment: Even better use `:compiler rspec | make %` or variation with `line('.')` to achieve the same effect but also get tests results in `quickfix` window.

Answer (score 1):

Vim has the [`:help :map-<unique>`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-%3Cunique%3E) modifier which makes the mapping fail if such mapping already exists.

```
au FileType ruby nnoremap <unique> <expr> <leader>t ...
```

You can suppress the error message with `:silent!`:

```
au FileType ruby silent! nnoremap <unique> <expr> <leader>t ...
```

Alternatively (and this is slightly better because it doesn't suppress any other errors in the mapping definition, like syntax errors), you could explicitly check for the mapping's existence via [`maparg()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#maparg%28%29):

```
au FileType ruby if empty(maparg('<leader>t', 'n')) | nnoremap <expr> <leader>t ... | endif
```

---

Note that this literally implements that (I understand) you're asking for; i.e. the first Ruby file will define the mapping, and any subsequent Ruby files are ignored; the mapping will always use the first file's name and line number. If you instead want to have different right-hand sides for the same mapping, depending on the currently edited file, the solution is a buffer-local mapping as per @PeterRincker's answer. But with that, you have to be inside the original Ruby buffer to trigger the correct mapping.

A remedy for that might be to recall the executed command-line from the *command-line history* (should happen automatically for your incomplete mapping, else via [`histadd()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#histadd%28%29)), so that you can easily recall the command from another file.

Comment: The mapping in `.vimrc` already works fine, the problem is about that it overwrite a hand crafted keybind if it exists. I could simply use another keybind, but is nice to save muscle memory. The solution for _after-directory_ will apply only once, I think